# Why does editing a PDF with Powerpoint increase the file-size?

Tags: pdf, powerpoint

I have two pdf images that I want to combine together and annotate. For quickness I did it in Powerpoint but exporting the new figure as a pdf creates a huge file: the original images are 78KB and 118KB and the pdf powerpoint creates is 2.9MB! The original images are quite complicated, one contains a lot of transparency and the other is a graph with a lot of data points, but I am confused why importing them to Powerpoint and then saving them increases the file size so much.

What are the reasons for this, and are there any ways I can stop it?

Comment: PDF isn't an image format; it's a composite file type that can contain images, vector graphics and other "stuff". From your description, it's likely that your PDFs contain lots of vector graphics, which tend to be much smaller in file size than the same content would be if it were rendered as an image.  And when you move PDF into PPT, it's almost certainly converted into an image. That's likely the cause here.

Comment: Hmm, okay right. So powerpoint converts the PDF files into some vector graphic format and then ppt's conversion of that image back to PDF is much less efficient than the original PDF description of the vector graphic?

Comment: When you say you have two PDF images, I'm assuming that you're bringing graphics from a PDF into PPT to combine them, then saving as PDF.  Is that correct?  And if so, how exactly are you bringing the PDF graphics into PPT?

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint file holds your PDF internally in case they move around relative to each other.  In the settings you should find an option to compress images to the resolution of the presentation.  Text PDF is likely to be in a very high resolution, so this can take down the size of the document.  Especially if you have a lot of images that are very small on the screen.